# JQUERY multi selection $( $(this) + other items )

Tags: jquery-selectors

In JQuery is possible to do **something like**:

```
$( $(this).parent(), $("#myid"), $("li"), ... );
```

In this way obviously **NOT work**, it's **only to explain**...

Comment: what are u trying to do, actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you have one set selected, and you would like to add more elements to that set?

Try JQuery's [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method.

Comment: Good. You should vote my answer up and/or accept it, to officially log your satisfaction. Glad I could help :)